# Issue with refreshing AWS Amplify token in Next.js using NextAuth and fetchAuthSession

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, next-auth

**Description:**

I am working on a Next.js 13 project where I use NextAuth for authentication and AWS Amplify (v6) for managing authentication flow. I've encountered an issue when attempting to handle a new ID token after the old one has expired.

**Problem:**

On the client side, I am successfully able to obtain a new token using the **`fetchAuthSession`** function from **`aws-amplify`**. However, I am facing difficulties implementing this on the server side within NextAuth callbacks.

**Code:**

```
export const authOption: NextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: "/signin",
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET as string,
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user, trigger, session }) {
      if (user) {
        const { exp } = jwtDecode<{ exp: number }>(user.access_token as string);
        return {
          user: {
            uuid: user.uuid,
            username: user.username,
            email: user.email,
          },
          accessToken: user.access_token,
          accessTokenExpiry: exp * 1000,
        };
      }
      const { exp } = jwtDecode<{ exp: number }>(token.accessToken as string);

      // Return previous token if the access token has not expired yet
      if (Date.now() <= exp * 1000) {
        return token;
      }
      // Get new token
      const newToken = (await fetchAuthSession()).tokens?.idToken?.toString() || ""; // This works on the client side
            const { exp: newTokenExp } = jwtDecode<{ exp: number }>(newToken);
            return { 
                ...token,
                accessToken: newToken,
                accessTokenExpiry: newTokenExp,
            }
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      return {
        ...session,
        ...token,
      };
    },
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "creds",
      credentials: { ... },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        //sign in and get user data and resolve
        return Promise.resolve({ ... });
      },
    }),
  ],
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOption);

export { handler as GET, handler as POST };
```

**Expecting:**

after token expire i get new token using aws-amplify(v6)

**Error:**

[next-auth][error][JWT_SESSION_ERROR]
https://next-auth.js.org/errors#jwt_session_error Invalid token specified {
message: 'Invalid token specified',

**Environment:**

- Next.js version: 13.5.4
- NextAuth version: "^4.23.1
- AWS Amplify version: v6(^6.0.6)

Any insights or code examples would be greatly appreciated.